# Call to a member function tokens() on null on Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, authentication

I get this error when i am trying to logout the user

```
  public function logout(Request $request)
    {
       $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the API route inner the Sanctum Auth middleware like below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {    
  Route::post('logout',   [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

`Auth::user()->token()` is only valid by passing the Sanctum middleware.
[Check this #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeGWU.png)
[Check this #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm0Hp.png)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, Change this code in your `Controller.php` to,

```
public function logout(Request $request){
    Auth::user()->tokens()->delete();
    return [
        'message' => 'logged out'
    ];
}
```

And make sure your Route POST request is protected in `api.php`, change the code to below

```
Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `token()` instead of `tokens()`

```
$request->user()->token()->delete();
```

Or you can use it as below.

```
Auth::user()->tokens->each(function($token, $key) {
    $token->delete();
});
```

by using revoke

```
$user = $request->user();

foreach ($user->tokens as $token) {
    $token->revoke();
}
```